# How do I place a grid wrapper under a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to make an "example page" of all the layouts (so one under the other) How do I place a grid wrapper under a flex container and not be shown in the same line? if I remove the `display: flex` it automatically goes under but flex remains in the same line.

And why do they both have the same salmon background color?

Thanks.

[image]

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.flex-wrapper>div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: salmon;
}


/* grid */

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border: 5px solid purple;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid-wrapper>div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.box3 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexbox Layout</h1>
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="box1">One</div>
  <div class="box2">Two</div>
  <div class="box3">Three</div>
  <!--Grid-->
  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="box1">One</div>
    <div class="box2">Two</div>
    <div class="box3">Three</div>
    <div class="box4">Four</div>
    <div class="box5">Five</div>
    <div class="box6">Six</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `.grid-wrapper` is also a flex item (it's a child of `.flex-wrapper`). And you've applied the salmon color to flex items with `flex-wrapper > div { background-color: salmon }`. Therefore, all four flex items (including the grid wrapper) will have a salmon background.

Comment: If you want the grid wrapper on its own row, set the flex container to `flex-wrap: wrap` (`no-wrap` is the default), and set the grid container to `flex-basis: 100%`.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the boxes of box in a container and put the add a `flex-direction` to `column` property in your `flex-wrapper` css class selector

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.flex-wrapper .box-container > div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: salmon;
}


/* grid */

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border: 5px solid purple;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid-wrapper>div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.box3 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexbox Layout</h1>
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="box-container">
     <div class="box1">One</div>
     <div class="box2">Two</div>
     <div class="box3">Three</div>
 </div>

  <!--Grid-->
  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="box1">One</div>
    <div class="box2">Two</div>
    <div class="box3">Three</div>
    <div class="box4">Four</div>
    <div class="box5">Five</div>
    <div class="box6">Six</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> why do they both have the same salmon background color?

Because `.flex-wrapper > div` applies to every div that's an immediate child of flex-wrapper.

> How do I place a grid wrapper under a flex container and not be shown in the same line?

You could add a [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) rule to your flex-wrapper and set the grid item to be wide enough to wrap, as in the example below, but you might consider whether your outer container should be a grid instead of flex. You'd have more control that way.

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* <=== */
}

.flex-wrapper>div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: salmon;
}


/* grid */

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border: 5px solid purple;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  gap: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 100%; /* <=== */
}

.grid-wrapper>div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.box3 {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexbox Layout</h1>
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="box1">One</div>
  <div class="box2">Two</div>
  <div class="box3">Three</div>
  <!--Grid-->
  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="box1">One</div>
    <div class="box2">Two</div>
    <div class="box3">Three</div>
    <div class="box4">Four</div>
    <div class="box5">Five</div>
    <div class="box6">Six</div>
  </div>
</div>
```